# Find and show special character codes from nvarchar column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, string-manipulation

I want to know which special characters (line breaks, tabs, etc) are in my column of type `nvarchar`.
I know how I can select [which rows contain a specific character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872270/how-can-i-check-if-an-sql-result-contains-a-newline-character).

e.g. `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_column LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '%'`

However, I want to know which columns contain characters not in `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and then WHICH characters that are.
I also looked if I can just do a select on a column to display RAW text with all characters displayed (similar to Microsoft Word's display all characters for example), but I couldn't find how to do this either.

Comment: Can you show in your question what you would like the output to look like, in general? Perhaps also give a complete list of the things you need revealed.

Answer (score 6):

If you can live with one-for-one character replacement, use the [`TRANSLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql) function.

For example:

```
DECLARE @T table (c1 nvarchar(50) NULL);

INSERT @T (c1) VALUES 
(N'Hello' + NCHAR(9) + N'there' + NCHAR(10) + NCHAR(13));

SELECT
    TRANSLATE(
        T.c1, 
        -- tab, line feed, carriage return
        CONCAT(NCHAR(9), NCHAR(10), NCHAR(13)), 
        -- corresponding replacement codes
        CONCAT(NCHAR(9225), NCHAR(9226), NCHAR(9229)))
FROM @T AS T;
```

| Output |
| --- |
| Hello␉there␊␍ |

It's up to you to choose the replacement characters. I used standard ones from the [Unicode 'Control Pictures' block](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2400).

Otherwise, use nested [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) calls to replace e.g. a tab character with '{tab}'.

When dealing with `nvarchar` data, it is important to prefix literals with N to produce Unicode. You should also use the Unicode functions like [`NCHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/nchar-transact-sql) instead of `CHAR`.